# How to load model from H2O Web UI Flow to python?

Tags: python, h2o

I want to save a model (export) from H2O Web UI and load in python. Can it be done? Can the opposite be done?
If so how? For automl?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the model you save from Flow or Python (i.e. one of the APIs) can be loaded and used in another API (you just need to make sure that the binary model you save uses the same version as the running H2O Cluster where you want to upload the model)

Saving a model using Flow is described [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/flow.html#exporting-and-importing-models)

Saving and loading a model is also described [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/save-and-load-model.html#saving-and-loading-a-model)

Comment: Thanks Lauren. One more thing: Can I retrain the exported model or is it only for prediction? What happens with stacked models?

Comment: yes you can use checkpointing please see the user guide: Thanks! http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/checkpointing-models.html